# insert previous row values for missing columns in the next row into the database using python

Tags: python-3.x, database

I have two rows 'A' ad 'B' in Database with same column names. But they populate values based on some parameter x in the first column. 
Row B has some column values missing and I want to fill those columns with values available in row A for similar column.

For example,

```
             a     b   c   d   e    f    g  h     
     Row A   24  -24  23  -22  51  -51  31 -31 
     Row B   23  -25  26  -23
```

I want to replicate same values for row B as in row A for last for columns(i.e from e to h columns). How can I do it in python?